# How to change the plot scale?

Tags: plotting, scaling

How to change the top plot so that it looks like the bottom one?
I changed the range of X and Y but it always looks the same way.
[image] [image]

---

I know, the formula is long :)

```
ContourPlot[(1/((2*Pi)*(x^2 + y^2)^1.5))*(2*ArcTan [y/x]* 
 x^4) + (-Pi*(y^4) - 
Pi*(x^4) + (2*ArcTan [y/x]* x^4) + (4*x*
  y^3) + (Sin[2*ArcTan[y/x]]*x^4) - (Sin[2*ArcTan[y/x]]*
  y^4) + (4*(x^2)*(y^2)*ArcTan[y/x])) - (2*
Pi*(x^2)*(y^2)), {y, -50, 50}, {x, 0, 60}, PlotTheme -> "Classic", ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", "Reverse"}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Please, show Mathematica code you use to get these plots.

Comment: I added the screenshot.

Comment: it is better if you could edit your question and post the plain text code there as it is a little hard to copy code from an image.

Comment: Think about it: do you think it shows consideration for people who might help you to have them manually retype code that you already have, instead of providing it in a form that can be copied?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I use Mathematica for the first time.

Comment: You may remove `ScalingFunctions -> ...` option and exchange ranges for `x` and `y` like this: ContourPlot[..., {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, -10}, ...], if needed you can also add `Contours -> 20` or other appropriate value.

Comment: I need inverted axis system YX not XY and both axis have to be reversed. Not normal type but from plus to minus so ScalingFunctions must stay.  I just need to have plot like the bottom one but if I change range of X and Y and try to zoom out the plot  nothing change